# How can calculate the size of any file in C++ or Visual C++/.NET or C#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the file size in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380839)

How can I calculate the size of any file in C++ or [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++#32-bit_versions)/[.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) or [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)?

I mean a .exe, .txt, .doc, etc. file.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean "calculate"?

You just ask the file system, "how big is that file?", and it gives you the length, no calculation involved.

What is your question exactly?

How to do that in C#?

Here's code that will give you the length of a file, there are other ways as well:

```
long length = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\test.exe").Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in C++ this way:

Taken directly from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

```
// Obtaining file size
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    long begin,end;
    ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
    begin = myfile.tellg();
    myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
    end = myfile.tellg();
    myfile.close();
    cout << "size is: " << (end-begin) << " bytes.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need for the first tellg and (end - begin) statement, just print out end.

Comment: Yeah I suppose they aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the size of the File, you can do this in C#:

```
long size = new System.IO.FileInfo("<path to file>").Length;
```

Comment: I work hiding data in Ip packet I will divid the file to bits for that I want know the length

Answer (score 0):

Another variant that matches your request -- Visual C++ using Windows File Management API:

```
LARGE_INTEGER liFileSize;
HANDLE hFile;
// open/create file 
GetFileSizeEx(hFile, &liFileSize);
// close handle
```

Answer (score 0):

Use stat.

`struct stat buf;
fstat(fd, &buf);
int size = buf.st_size;`

Comment: That's neither C++, Visual C++ nor C#.

Comment: it's as simple as it gets, I use it in my c++ programming for file size retrieval. My ftp client relies completely on it, and it's worked great.