# Determining file size in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, text

How do I determine the size of a text file?

I know that I could just count characters, but the file will be several MB's large.

Comment: I found this via Google: http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-size-vbnet

Comment: Related, but for C#: *[How do you get the file size in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380839)*

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
Dim myFile As New FileInfo("file.txt")
Dim sizeInBytes As Long = myFile.Length
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wouldn't have asked if I had known it was so simple.

Answer (score 19):

```
Dim size As Long = FileLen("file.txt")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.filelen

Answer (score 3):

The use of `file` can be dangerous as it is also the name of a class.
It is better to code it as follows:

```
Dim myFile As New FileInfo("file.txt")
Dim sizeInBytes As Long = myFile.Length
```

Comment: This is true enough, but you really should come up with a better name than `myFile`. It's a good opportunity to write something *descriptive*. IntelliSense makes using long names easy enough.

Comment: -1 for ripping off the code in the answer before it. This is pretty much a direct copy of the accepted answer.

Comment: +1 because using reserved words (or anything like it) is an awful practice and I'm glad this comment stopped me from doing so.

Comment: This should be an edit or a comment to the previous answer, not a separate answer. -1

Answer (score -4):

The code from the other answer does not check the correct size of the file:

```
Dim myFile As New FileInfo("file.txt")
Dim sizeInBytes As Long = MyFile.Length
```

Try this code instead

```
Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo = _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\testfile.txt")
MsgBox("File C:\testfile.txt is " & infoReader.Length & " bytes.")
```

It is from *[How to: Determine a File's Size in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99h600fc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

Comment: Why would the first code snippet not work? The file specification is different for the two code snippets, "file.txt" for the first code snippet (relative file specification) and "C:\testfile.txt" for the second (absolute file specification). The first one depends on the current directory. Wouldn't the first code snippet work if it used "C:\testfile.txt" instead of "file.txt"?

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong. ***The only reason the first code snippet won't work is if you do not have the permissions to read the file. The first code snippet is just a shortened version of the second, further rendering your 'does not work' invalid..***