# Can I stop my textbox from crashing when loading in too much data into it?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Not sure if this is something really simple that I haven't noticed. Or just a simple try/catch (I guess most likely).

I have a textbox on a form. It takes in data from another text file which is very large (lets assume 1Mb) and in a lot of cases it can take it but in some cases the program crashes when loading the file.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Check the file size before you load it into your TextBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to read the file size of the text file before loading it into your text box. If the length of the file is greater than the capacity of your text box, you can prevent the text box from being filled.

You can use a function like [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) to determine the size of the text file.

```
    Dim AppDataLocation As String = "C:\Files\TestFiles\" 

    Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(AppDataLocation) 

    For Each fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo In _
                      SourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos 
        Dim FileText As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText _
                      (AppDataLocation & fileSystemInfo.Name)         
    Next
```

Alternately, you can use [FileInfo.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) as seen in this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175630/determine-file-size-vb-net).

```
Dim file As New FileInfo("file.txt")
Dim sizeInBytes As Long = file.Length
```