# Is it normal for GC to trigger this often?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Today I noticed that a little program I made triggered GC quite often during the first 10~20 seconds of the programs lifetime. After which it barely triggers ever again.
[image]

During this period of time only 1 function runs, which is the one below. Obtaining ~2k of file paths, and filtering out most of them.

```
 public static string[] FilterFiles(string path)
    {
        // Fetch the files from given directory
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);

        // Delete all files that are to small
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string fullFile = default(string);

            try
            {
                fullFile = File.ReadAllText(file);
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (fullFile.Length < Settings.MinimumFileSize)
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }

        // Obtain the new list without the small files
        List<string> cleanFiles = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(path));
        List<string> cleanReturn = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(path));

        // Remove files we have handled before
        foreach (string file in cleanFiles)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Settings.ExtractFolder + "\\" + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "_Extract.xml"))
            {
                cleanReturn.Remove(file);
            }
        }

        return cleanReturn.ToArray();
    }
```

Is it normal for GC to trigger this often in this period of time?

Comment: Does it make any performance degradation?

Comment: How long are those strings you're manipulating?

Comment: @dotctor forcing gc off saves ~2 seconds. So yeah.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Files paths, < 100 characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, yes. You are creating tons of objects with a short lifetime, and those are disposed as soon as possible.

Try not to read the entire file. Instead, just [get the `FileInfo` to get the file size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380839/993547).

Here you are enumerating the directory listing twice, which is unnecessary too:

```
List<string> cleanFiles = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(path));
List<string> cleanReturn = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(path));
```

Also here, a ton of strings are created due to string concatenation:

```
Settings.ExtractFolder + "\\" + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "_Extract.xml"
```

Use a `StringBuilder` or `string.Format` there, and try to do as much in front as possible.

Comment: Not reading the entire file but using the FileInfo reduced it to a mere 3 GC's. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to read in an entire file just to find its length. Just do: `long length = new FileInfo(file).Length;`.

You can enumerate files without reading all the file names into an array too, by using `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)`.

I think you could rewrite your entire function like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> FilterFiles(string path)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
    {
        if (new FileInfo(file).Length < Settings.MinimumFileSize)
            File.Delete(file);
        else if (!File.Exists(Settings.ExtractFolder + "\\" + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "_Extract.xml"))
            yield return file;
    }
}
```

And then either use `foreach` to enumerate all the files like so:

```
foreach (string file in FilterFiles(myPath))
    ...
```

Or if you want to force all the small files to be deleted before you apply the rest of your logic, use `ToArray()` first, before the `foreach`:

```
foreach (string file in FilterFiles(myPath).ToArray())
    ...
```

But to answer your question: Yes, the GC will potentially run often if you create lots of small objects. And it will especially run if you create some big strings: How big are those files you're reading into memory?