# C#: How to show attributes of a folder/file in treeview

Tags: c#, .net, directory, treeview, nodes

Create a GUI application that will provide functionality to show complete hierarchy of files and folders
for a specified folder:
1. Each file/folder should be qualified with:
a. File/Folder name
b. File size (bytes) (only for files)

How do i get the folder/file name and size to show in treeview a node?

Comment: See my recent answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133736/how-to-create-and-save-an-xml-file-containing-complete-hierarchy-of-files-and-fo/44136611#44136611.  My answer creates both a treeview and a xml file.

Comment: Thank you, finally some things are more clear. I understood immediately that i have to make an object [] to get all of the attributes but i still have problems understanding how to get them into the treeview. I still have to workout the treeview and node use. They confuse me. Any good reference on them?

Comment: Run my code.  First create the xml, then the treeview.  The code works.  Viewing the xml will help you understand the code better.  The code takes the xml and loads into the treeview.  You can eliminate the later.