# Import directory text to create tree structure

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree

I have several files that consist of folder path that looks like

```
//Fs1/userA/
//Fs1/userA/documents/
//Fs1/userB/
//Fs2/userC/documents
```

I want to do analysis of which folders have x number direct sub folders. E.g. userD have 120 sub folders directly under it, not inclusive of deeper folders.

And I have huge collection of such files, some of them containing few hundred k rows.

I've thought of using radix tree, but it doesn't perform if I have to traverse down all its children to find the number of direct sub folders.

Also considered putting it into a database server to query, which might be easier to implement, but I wanted to try using .Net for analysis without sql servers. Any help?

Comment: You can use an xml file for a dattabase.  Did a project last week that may help.  The application reads a folder (and subfolders), creates an xml, and then put xml into a treeview for displaying.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133736/how-to-create-and-save-an-xml-file-containing-complete-hierarchy-of-files-and-fo/44136611#44136611

Comment: That will not work in my case as I'm exporting file servers backed by SAN with 50+TB of content

Comment: For reading your posting it sounded like to didn't want a database and was looking for alternative.  But now that you say you have 50+TB of data there isn't any real alternative.If you do store in database you should use stored procedure for the queries and just use Net and just use Net for final  analysis.

Comment: @jdweng the 50tb is actually file size in total, the csv are in mb. I've tried using Patricia tree, it loads really fast, like 2mil items in seconds. Using a dictionary takes couple of min for a fee hundred k rows and doing analysis is a pain

Comment: I update my code to now include a treeview.  The code checks folder and subfolder for all files and when size or number of files exceed a limit puts the results into the treeview.

Answer (score 0):

I took my xml project and removed xml.  Now I just get totals.  Maybe this will work for you.  The code checks folder and subfolder for all files and when size or number of files exceed a limit puts the results into the treeview.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace CheckFileSizes
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int FILE_SIZE_CHECK = 10000000;
        const int FILE_COUNT_CHECK = 1000;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = @"c:\temp";
            textBoxTotalFolderSizeMin.Text = FILE_SIZE_CHECK.ToString();
            textBoxNumberOfFilesMin.Text = FILE_COUNT_CHECK.ToString();

        }
        private void buttonBrowseForFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
            textBoxFolderName.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
        }

        private void buttonMakeTree_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(textBoxFolderName.Text))
            {
                MyDirectory root = MyDirectory.root;

                TreeNode rootNode = MakeTreeRecursive(textBoxFolderName.Text, root);
                textBoxTotalNumberOfFiles.Text = root.totalNumberOfFiles.ToString();
                textBoxTotalSize.Text = ((long)root.totalSize).ToString();

                if (rootNode == null)
                {
                    string rootNodeText = string.Format("Folder: '{0}', Number of Files: '{1}', File Size: '{2}'",
                        textBoxFolderName.Text,
                        textBoxTotalNumberOfFiles.Text,
                        textBoxTotalSize.Text
                    );
                    rootNode = new TreeNode(rootNodeText);
                }
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                treeView1.ExpandAll();


            }
        }
        private TreeNode MakeTreeRecursive(string folder, MyDirectory myDirectory)
        {
            TreeNode node = null;

            myDirectory.name = folder.Substring(folder.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);

            myDirectory.numberOfFiles = 0;
            myDirectory.size = 0.0f;

            foreach (FileInfo fInfo in dInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                try
                {
                    float fSize = fInfo.Length;
                    myDirectory.size += fSize;
                    myDirectory.numberOfFiles += 1;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error : CAnnot Access File '{0}'", fInfo.Name);
                }
            }
            myDirectory.totalSize = myDirectory.size;
            myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles = myDirectory.numberOfFiles;
            foreach (string subFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
            {
                if (myDirectory.children == null) myDirectory.children = new List<MyDirectory>();
                MyDirectory childDirectory = new MyDirectory();
                myDirectory.children.Add(childDirectory);

                TreeNode childNode = MakeTreeRecursive(subFolder, childDirectory);
                if (childNode != null)
                {
                    if (node == null)
                    {
                        node = new TreeNode();
                    }
                    node.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                }

                myDirectory.totalSize += childDirectory.totalSize;
                myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles += childDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles;
            }

            if ((myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles >= long.Parse(textBoxNumberOfFilesMin.Text)) || myDirectory.totalSize >= float.Parse(textBoxTotalFolderSizeMin.Text))
            {
                if (node == null)
                {
                    node = new TreeNode();
                }
                string childNodeText = string.Format("Folder: '{0}', Number of Files: '{1}', File Size: '{2}'",
                    folder,
                    myDirectory.totalNumberOfFiles,
                    myDirectory.totalSize
                );
                node.Text =  childNodeText;
            }
            return node;
        }

    }
    public class MyDirectory
    {
        public static MyDirectory root = new MyDirectory();
        public List<MyDirectory> children { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }
        public long totalNumberOfFiles = 0;
        public int numberOfFiles = 0;
        public float size = 0.0f;
        public float totalSize = 0.0f;
    }
}
```