# How to show details of selected tree node

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, treeview

What I need is when a tree node is selected, the application needs to show the selected folder (or file) details listed. The details should be shown in the same window but separately from the folder hierarchy tree.

I have created app that recursively searches trough files/folders and writes XML file that is later used to fill tree view. My problem is when i fill tree view, it fills it with attributes from xml(size, creation date, last modified ...) and I don't want that, I want it to display just names of files/folders and when I click on tree node that it displays details of specific file/folder.

I used this code to do all that [How to create and save an XML file containing complete hierarchy of files and folders for a specified folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133736/how-to-create-and-save-an-xml-file-containing-complete-hierarchy-of-files-and-fo)

But the problem is in these lines of code, they display all information in tree view

```
           foreach (var att in xElement.Attributes())
           {
                treeNode.Text = treeNode.Text + " " + att.Name.LocalName + ":" + att.Value;
           }
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem, how to display file/folder details when tree node is selected

This is my whole code

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        XDocument xDoc = null;
        string path = null;

        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        
        /// <summary>
        /// When button Browse is clicked:
        /// - opens folder browser and lets user choose which folder to display
        /// - creates XML file based on selected path
        /// - fills treeView with that XML file
        /// </summary>
        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listDetails.Items.Clear();
            FolderBrowserDialog fwd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if(fwd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                lblPath.Text = "Path: " + fwd.SelectedPath; // Shows path selected by user 
                path = fwd.SelectedPath; // stores that path in string for later use
            }
            CreateXML(); 
            CreateTree();
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Recursively search through files and folders to create XML file
        /// - 
        /// </summary>     
        private double Recursion(string folder, XElement folderElement)
        {
            folderElement.SetValue(folder);
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);

            int number_Of_Files = 0; // Number of files in folder
            double folder_Size = 0; // Folder size in bytes

            FileInfo[] files = null;
            //DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

            try
            {
                files = dirInfo.GetFiles(); //Returns file list from current directory

                if (files != null)
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo f in files) //Lists all files in file list and 
                    {
                        double fileSize = f.Length;
                        folder_Size += fileSize;
                        folderElement.Add(new XElement("File", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("Size",fileSize + "(bytes)"),
                        new XAttribute("Created", f.CreationTime.ToShortDateString()),
                        new XAttribute("LastAccess", f.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString()),
                        new XAttribute("LastModified", f.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString()),
                        f.Name

                    }));
                        number_Of_Files += 1; //Increments everytime it finds file in folder 
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                writeErrorLog(e.Message);
            }

            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                writeErrorLog(e.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                //Lists all sub folders in current directory
                foreach (string subDirs in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
                {
                    XElement childDirectory = new XElement("Directory");
                    folderElement.Add(childDirectory);
                    double dirSize = Recursion(subDirs, childDirectory); //Call Recursion for found sub folder in folder 
                    folder_Size += dirSize;
                }
                // Writes attributes of XML folder element 
                folderElement.Add(new XAttribute[] {
                new XAttribute("FolderSize", folder_Size + "(bytes)"),
                new XAttribute("NumberOfFiles", number_Of_Files)
            });                
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                writeErrorLog(e.Message);
            }

            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
                writeErrorLog(e.Message);
            }
            return folder_Size;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates tree node 
        /// -
        /// </summary>
        private void AddTreeNode(XElement xElement, TreeNode treeNode)
        {
            foreach (var att in xElement.Attributes())
            {
                treeNode.Text = treeNode.Text + " " + att.Name.LocalName + ":" + att.Value;
            }

            foreach (XElement childElement in xElement.Elements())
            {
                TreeNode Node = treeNode.Nodes[treeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(childElement.Value))];
                AddTreeNode(childElement, Node);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates XML file 
        /// - If directory exists in path selected by user
        /// - sets root element for XML file
        /// - recursively search through files and folders in that path to create XML file
        /// </summary>
        private void CreateXML()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                string header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Directory></Directory> ";
                xDoc = XDocument.Parse(header);
                XElement root = xDoc.Root;

                Recursion(path, root);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// - Clears tree view everytime method is called 
        /// - Checks if XML document is null
        /// - If not creates tree node instance 
        /// - Uses method AddTreeNode to create tree nodes 
        /// - Fills tree view with those nodes
        /// </summary>
        private void CreateTree()
        {
            folderBrowserTree.Nodes.Clear();
            if(xDoc != null)
            {
                TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode(xDoc.Root.FirstNode.ToString());
                AddTreeNode(xDoc.Root, rootNode);
                folderBrowserTree.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
                //folderBrowserTree.ExpandAll(); //If wanted tree view can display tree nodes as expanded
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// When tree node is selected, displays tree node details in list view
        /// </summary>
        private void folderBrowserTree_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
        {            
            listDetails.Items.Clear(); // Clears list view everytime this method is called
            TreeDetails();
            string str = folderBrowserTree.SelectedNode.Text;

            var details = str.Split(); // Splits string by whitespaces
            listDetails.Items.Add("Name: " + details[0]);

            for (int i = 1; i < details.Length; i++)
            {
                listDetails.Items.Add(details[i]);
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your binding code?

Comment: The code you show is just setting a treeNode's text to a compilation of all the attributes (`xElement.Attributes()`) names and values.  I presume outside of this loop you are looping through the elements in your xml tree and adding a node for each.  But "presume" does not help us help you.  You need to show more code.

Comment: What do you mean by binding code?

Comment: I edited my question and here is my whole code. Thanks in advance