# Choosing a random ints from a txt file in c# windows forms app

Tags: c#, int

i am a newbie in here so i apogolize if i make mistakes. Now i have a program that takes a random int from a text file that contains one million digits of number Pi. the lenght is also random but it shouldn't be longer than 128 digits. I looked for it so much but i was able to find this code that makes my computer get frozen by the cpu usage being %100.

```
string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath+ "\\pi.txt");
        Random rnd1 = new Random();
        textBox2.Text=(allLines[rnd1.Next(allLines.Length)]);
```

also when i got the random ints, i need it to be printed into textBox2's text.
i am terribly sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what your issue is.  What is not working?

Comment: the pc is getting stuck and not printing out the random value i want

Comment: It's not getting stuck, at least not in the code you provided. How big is the file?

Comment: what *is* it printing out?  What do you mean "stuck"?  You're being too vague.  What *exactly* is happening?  Like literally, what is happening?

Comment: 976kb and it contains a million digits

Comment: it becomes unusable and until i shut down the app it stays like that

Comment: Well have you tried debugging it?  Stepping through the code and watching what it's actually doing, observing the values in your variables?

Comment: A little more code and the first few lines of ```pi.txt``` would help to understand the problem. How big is pi.txt anyways(3 MB? one for the digit, one for \r one for \n times 1 Million)? Might be simply loading time of the file which is the problem. You could debug it line by line to identify the line which is causing the issue.

Comment: umm that is the problem, whenever i execute the program to understand whats happening the pc get unusable i can't click anything, its got 4gigs of ram tho:)

Comment: I'm not talking about just executing it.  I'm talking about debugging it, setting a break point, etc.

Comment: well i found out when i put the breakpoint to the start button in my forms app. thanks to you rory.ap, and i Confirmed that the problem is same that FrankM says thanks to him and all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to erad all the file just for couple of bytes. consider the solution below.

Please Note that I didnt include Random method.

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[10];
var file = 'path/to/your/file';
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)))
{
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(<startingPosition>, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    reader.Read(byteArray, 0, <numberOfLinesToRead>);
}

string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```

Comment: so this one translates into bytes to make it perfomable i think? but where do i put the file location in this code sir?

Comment: `new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)` - the `file` parameter is your path

Comment: it isn't my down vote:) heck i can't even vote yet because of my reputation:D

Comment: umm i didn't get the seekToPosition part,

Comment: seekToPosition: you can [get the file length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20863065/243245), subtract the length you're going to read and then generate a random number between 0 and that to use as a starting position.

Comment: starting position is random from the file

Comment: what you are suggesting is trivial, you first need to read random location from file in order to get your second starting position.

Comment: so i can type whatever to starting position since it is gonna be replaced? i think, i am terribly sorry for being such a noob:)

Comment: you can use this (new Random()).Next((new FileInfo("path/to/file")).Length)

Comment: ok, thank you very much Simonare, and other very kind people that helped.:)