# how to get file size of uploaded fiel in web api in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to get the file size of the uploaded file without saving it on the disk. I am getting the file in controller like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIncomingFile(IFormFile file){
 // my code here
}
```

Comment: Did you try to read `Content-Lenght`  header? Does the request contain any other data except file?

Comment: Have you tried using [IFormFile.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.length?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-iformfile-length) ?

Comment: This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380839/20654632

Comment: IFormFile only have .Length property. Not ContentLength

Comment: The `Length` property maps to the `Content-Length` header. Did you use them? If you know about the `Length` property, why the question? Did you encounter another problem?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk No, i am not using `FileInfo`. I am using `IFormFile`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i didn't know that .Length property gives the file actual file size. I am new to .net core and c# world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Length` property of the `IFormFile` object to get the file size. The `Length` property returns the size of the file in bytes.

Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetIncomingFile(IFormFile file){
    long fileSize = file.Length;
    // Do something with the file size
    ...
}
```